# Overwrite FormControl.disabled with CSS or HTML attribute

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an angular date picker where only the date picker button should be available to the user and not the input, since we want to prevent false input. Therefore I need to disable the input field so it is readonly and the user can only pick from the date picker. The problem is I cannot use the "disabled" attribute on the input element, since it is overwritten by the form control. But I can't just disable it in the component with `dateFormControl.disable()`, since we are using the status changes of the form control (from invalid to valid) for some other logic and this way it would always have the status 'disabled'. Is there any way I can disable the input without actually disabling it? Like making it non-clickable with CSS or something?

My template code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>{{'cart.requested-delivery-date' |cxTranslate}}</mat-label>

          <input
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="picker"
            [min]="data.startDate"
            (dateInput)="formSubmitted$.next()"
            [formControl]="namedDeliveryDateControl"
          >

          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="picker"
          >
            <mat-icon
              class="icon-calendar"
              matDatepickerToggleIcon
            ></mat-icon>
          </mat-datepicker-toggle>

          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

          <mat-error
            *ngIf="namedDeliveryDateControl.errors?.invalidDate"
            class="fs-14"
          >
            {{ 'ecommerce.ndd.validation.error.invalidDate.' + namedDeliveryDateControl.errors.invalidDate | cxTranslate }}
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

And why I cant just disable the form control:

```
this.hold(this.namedDeliveryDateControl.statusChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.namedDeliveryDateControl.status),
      pairwise(),
      tap(([oldValue, newValue]) => {
        this.cartFacade.setEntryFormValidity(this.get('entry').entryNumber, newValue);

        // Reload the cart to refresh the error message for #notOrderable errors in the cart-item-component
        if(oldValue === 'INVALID' && newValue === 'VALID') {
          this.multiCartService.reloadCart(OCC_CART_ID_CURRENT);
        }
      }
    )));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to let the user use the input if he wants and the validate the input? Why having an input at all if you don't want it to be used?

Comment: @AmauryHanser I need the input in order to use the mat-date-picker I think. But as the date picker comes with a button and a modal to actually pick the date, I don't really want to give the user the option to use the input field as well.

Comment: Then read the docs, you can do it without any custom dev: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#disabling-parts-of-the-datepicker

Comment: I don't think so. I already read through the whole thing. If you found anything, please tell me :)

I have fixed it now with the 'readonly' attribute and some styling adjustments. That way it is still active but not usable.

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'readonly' attribute to disable the input field and some css for the typical look of being disabled. That way the form control status didn't interfere with the disabled state both my criteria were fulfilled.